# Why OdbcDataReader requires a live connection

Tags: mysql, vb.net, reader

this code will give error

```
    Dim mysql As String = " Select roll_no,std_name from student"
    Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand(mysql, conn)
    conn.Open()
    Dim reader As OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    conn.Close()
    If reader.HasRows = True Then

    End If
```

but this is working fine

```
    Dim mysql As String = " Select roll_no,std_name from student"
    Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand(mysql, conn)
    conn.Open()
    Dim reader As OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If reader.HasRows = True Then

    End If
    conn.Close()
```

Why reader requires an open connection always to read data from database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reader is designed to actually read the results from the DB, then be closed after use, and is the lowest level of DB access in ADO.NET.

I rarely use a DataReader anymore, and prefer the DataAdapter.Fill method to retrieve results and return a dataset/table. Behind the scenes, the Adapter opens a datareader and fills the dataset.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx